# Resources.NotFoundException when constructing ArrayAdaptor

Tags: java, android

This is a my .java file:

```
package com.example.rohitkulkarni.readingfile;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        try{

                InputStream inputreader = getAssets().open("myaddress.txt");
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputreader));



                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
           boolean hasNextLine =true;
            while (hasNextLine){

               String line =  buffreader.readLine();
                lines.add(line);
               hasNextLine = line != null;


            }
                    tv.setText((CharSequence) lines);

            //exception here:
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.id.listView,lines);

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

           inputreader.close();

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        }catch(IOException e){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am working with getAsset all working fine but only ArrayAdaptor is not working I tried all possible combinations but it is not working. It is working with simple string array.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: post your exception log as well

Comment: Process: com.example.rohitkulkarni.readingfile, PID: 13239
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c004f type #0x12 is not valid
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2603)

Answer (score 1):

String line =  buffreader.readLine();

//i found that he was taking null value so checking for it

> if(line != null);

```
            lines.add(line);
           hasNextLine = line != null;
```

//not it is working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

The middle argument is wrong, from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List<T>)):

> The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

But you are passing an id:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.id.listView, lines);
```

This should be a layout:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.???, lines);
```

Comment: Process: com.example.rohitkulkarni.readingfile, PID: 16421
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c004f type #0x12 is not valid
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2603)

Comment: "I tried with ListView id but it is not working" Yeah, I know! It needs to be a  layout as I have said in my answer.

Comment: You say " It is working with simple string array." so carefully compare the difference for when you have it working and when you do not.

Comment: got the answer it is taking null value at last

Comment: That statement doesn't make any sense on it's own. My answer has nothing to do with `null`. If you want you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.id.listView,lines);
```

In this line you have passed a ListView id.

But the constructor expecting a Layout to inflate. So pass in a Layout.

Like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lines);
```

### EDIT

Also in this line.

`tv.setText((CharSequence) lines);`

`tv` is not defined in your activity. And if its a TextView you are setting an ArrayList to it. try `tv.setText(lines.toString())`

Comment: Process: com.example.rohitkulkarni.readingfile, PID: 18411
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)

Answer (score 0):

try to use..

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lines);
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this

Comment: try to set the adapter after try catch block, after closing the stream.